# Mongo DB subdocument query fails when attribute order changes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

To make it very simple

This is my sample document 'Address'

```
name : "User1",address : {street : "Street1", colony : "Colony1"}
```

**Query 1**

`db.address.find({ "address" : {street : "Street1", colony : "Colony1"} }` -Returns the document

**Query 2**

`db.address.find({ "address" : {colony : "Colony1", street : "Street1"} }` - Returns 0 rows.

Just the attribute order is changed, and the query fails.

P.S : The subdocument is dynamic, may have any number of attributes. So please dont suggest DOT function

**Asking in Another way**

```
name : "User1",address : {street : "Street1", colony : "Colony1"}
name : "User1",address : {path: "Patth1", venue : "Venue1"}
```

How do I query such a document, when I dont know the actual structure of one of the attribute

Comment: You seem to be lacking a description of what your data looks like, but the possibilities are listed in the provided answer.

Comment: I gave the complete document itself. The actual data inside mongo db

Comment: Then read the "answer" as the solution to that is there as well.

Comment: in ur insert query, change the address array to address object (one object not array). and the solution will  return zero

Comment: Changing your question drastically from it's original form is not acceptable behavoir here. You asked how to match "street" and "colony" in any order. **Not** how to match something that might be in a key you don't know the name of. In fact it actually makes what you are asking very unclear, as it is now not even clear what you are trying to match at all.

Comment: @madhairsilence What do you mean by "please dont suggest DOT function"? A query using dot notation is the way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

That is because your query in the current form is looking for an "exact match" of the document. So even if the document had additional fields the query would not match.

Use [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) instead:

```js
db.address.find({ 
    "address" : { 
        "$elemMatch": { "colony": "Colony1", "street": "Street1" }
    }
})
```

This performs "a query" on the specified array property. The "order" of elements or even "additional" elements does not matter then, just as with normal query conditions.

The `$elemMatch` operator allows "multiple" conditions to match on a sub-document in an array. This is different to using "dot notation" for each element which just tests that at least "one" element in the array matches either condition. This requires "all" conditions to be met in the same document.

---

Here is how it works:

```js
db.address.insert([
    { 
        "matched": "expected",
        "address": [
            { "street": "Street1", "colony": "Colony1" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "matched": "not expected",   
        "address": [
            { "street": "Street2", "colony": "Colony1" }
        ]
    },
    { 
        "matched": "expected",
        "address": [
            { "colony": "Colony1", "street": "Street1", "another": 1 }
        ]
    }
])
```

Then query:

```js
db.address.find({
    "address": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "colony": "Colony1", "street": "Street1"
        }
    }
})
```

Gets you:

```js
{
    "matched" : "expected",
    "address" : [
            {
                    "street" : "Street1",
                    "colony" : "Colony1"
            }
    ]
}
{
    "matched" : "expected",
    "address" : [
            {
                    "colony" : "Colony1",
                    "street" : "Street1",
                    "another": 1
            }
    ]
}
```

---

So if you don't get that then your documents don't even have "arrays" at all. like this:

```js
db.address.insert([
    { 
        "matched": "expected",
        "address": {
            "street": "Street1", "colony": "Colony1"
        }
    },
    {
        "matched": "not expected",   
        "address": {
            "street": "Street2", "colony": "Colony1"
        }

    },
    { 
        "matched": "expected",
        "address": {
            "colony": "Colony1", "street": "Street1", "another": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Then you rather than query for an "exact match", use ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to specify the full path to the fields:

```js
db.address.find({
    "address.street": "Street1",
    "address.colony": "Colony1"
})
```

Which matches your sub-document elements in your document in any order.

```js
{
    "matched" : "expected",
    "address" : {
            "street" : "Street1",
            "colony" : "Colony1"
    }
}
{
    "matched" : "expected",
    "address" : {
            "colony" : "Colony1",
            "street" : "Street1",
            "another" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I can see address is an array. But in my case, address is simple object.. i changed the insert statement for ur requirement and it failed

Comment: @madhairsilence There is also a simple object there and the example of how to query for it. Would have been nice if your question stated that.

Comment: in the question I mentioned that Sub document is dynamic, so i cannot use dot. secondly, changing address from array to object is not working. My structure is object , not array. If address is an array, your solution works, but if its simple object , it returns zero

Comment: @madhairsilence What do you mean "dynamic"? Does your document contain "address" with sub keys "street" and "colony" in any order or not? "Dot notation" is not **just** for arrays.

Comment: Assume this is a real address,. key is address and the value is any json of any format. i.e one address will have plot.no, another will have flat no. etc. but address is constant, I can query with that key

Comment: @madhairsilence Will you please actually **read** the answer, because it does not look like you are. There are "two" possible structures given because you initially did not post one, and there are "two" queries. Both with examples, both with returned results. If you are asking how to find "street1" in a field that might be called "street" or might be called "avenue" then that is not what your question asked. This answers the question ( very kindly in two ways ) as it was asked.

Comment: I infact tried ur answer right here. I changed the address : [  ]  to address : { } and it failed. Edited my question.